# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table and variable

```
DECLARE @FunctionValue nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @TSV_WithTarget TABLE
        (
            Transition_Set_Variable_ID INT,
            [Value] nvarchar(255),
            TargetTable nvarchar(255),
            TargetColumn nvarchar(255),
            FunctionValue nvarchar(255)
        )
```

The table contains the following data :

```
IF (SELECT FunctionValue 
    FROM @TSV_WithTarget 
    WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter
    AND FunctionValue IS NOT NULL ) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT FunctionValue 
    FROM @TSV_WithTarget 
END
```

[image]

apparently, this code right here produces the following error if I uncomment any of the commented out lines.

```
SET @FunctionValue = ( SELECT CASE
                    --WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'DATEADD%' THEN ( SELECT FunctionValue 
                    --                                          FROM @TSV_WithTarget 
                    --                                          WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter )
                    WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'GETDATE' THEN ( SELECT GETDATE() )
                    --WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'STORED PROCEDURE' THEN ( SELECT Changed_In_SP
                    --                                                  FROM BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable
                    --                                                  WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter )
                    --WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'SWITCH_USER' THEN ( SELECT 'hersem' )
                    WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'VALUE' THEN ( SELECT Name 
                                                            FROM BPE_T_VA_Value
                                                            WHERE Value_ID = ( SELECT Set_To_Value_ID
                                                                                FROM BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable
                                                                                WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter ) )
                    WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'VARIABLE' THEN ( SELECT Value_ID
                                                                FROM BPE_T_VA_Process_Instance_Value
                                                                WHERE Variable_ID = ( SELECT Set_To_Variable_ID
                                                                                        FROM BPE_T_VA_Transition_Set_Variable
                                                                                        WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter )
                                                                AND Process_Instance_ID = @Process_Instance_ID)
                    --ELSE ( SELECT FunctionValue )
                END AS FV
                FROM @TSV_WithTarget
                WHERE Transition_Set_Variable_ID = @TSV_Target_Counter
                AND FunctionValue IS NOT NULL )
```

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 83
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.`

I have no idea what this could be.

- The setting of @FunctionValue takes place in a WHILE loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the CASE expression must be of the same type. Hence it is necessary to replace

`SELECT GETDATE()` on `CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 101)` and `Value_ID` on `CAST(Value_ID AS nvarchar(255))`

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '04/29/2013' to data type int.`

Comment: and replace Value_ID on CAST(Value_ID AS nvarchar(255))

Comment: now it works, please add this to your original answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the column `FV` in the result table can get different types depends on the rows order in the table `@TSV_WithTarget`. You should convert ALL CASE results to ONE type `nvarchar`.

For example -  the first not NULL row is `GETDATE` so SQL defines `FV` as a `datetime`. And so on.